# Why my mongoose sample program cannot connect to mongoDB and I have no error report?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new in MongDB and I am trying to run sample code from the Mongoose

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html

I put the code in one of my router where I can connect to the MongoDB server using the MongoClient successfully.

However, when I was trying to replace the code with the sample of Mongoose, it could not work and have no error report there.

Here is the code I wrote to connect the MongoDB

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/project');

exports.userSignin = function (req, res) {


var user = req.body;
if (user) {
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {
       console.log('successful');
    });
} else {
    res.send(common.get_return_data(false, '', -1, 'no data received'));
}

};
```

I got no error in the command line

```
  server: { port: 3000 } }
  project:server Listening on port 3000 +0ms
POST /user/signin - - ms - -
POST /user/signin - - ms - -
POST /user/signin - - ms - -
```

It is strange because I set the listener to listen to the error.
And I start my mongoDB server as well.

> ```
> wireless-nat-inside:project Jiahui$ mongod --dbpath ./data
> 2017-04-16T11:36:16.147-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8341 port=27017 dbpath=./data 64-bit
> ```
>
> host=wireless-nat-inside.uiowa.edu
>       2017-04-16T11:36:16.148-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.3
>       2017-04-16T11:36:16.148-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: f07437fb5a6cca07c10bafa78365456eb1d6d5e1
>       2017-04-16T11:36:16.148-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
>       2017-04-16T11:36:16.148-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
>       2017-04-16T11:36:16.148-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
>       2017-04-16T11:36:16.148-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
>       2017-04-16T11:36:16.148-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
>       2017-04-16T11:36:16.148-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
>       2017-04-16T11:36:16.148-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "./data" } }
>       2017-04-16T11:36:16.151-0500 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in ./data created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so
>   setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
>       2017-04-16T11:36:16.151-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config:
>   create,cache_size=3584M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
>       2017-04-16T11:36:18.149-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>       2017-04-16T11:36:18.149-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
>       2017-04-16T11:36:18.150-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
>       2017-04-16T11:36:18.150-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>       2017-04-16T11:36:18.150-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>       2017-04-16T11:36:18.150-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at
>   least 1000
>       2017-04-16T11:36:18.162-0500 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory
>   './data/diagnostic.data'
>       2017-04-16T11:36:18.163-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017

In addition, the program did go into the if statement, which means the user is not empty there. I did the debug using the webstrom.

Comment: First of all, line 4 should read module.exports.userSignup

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger Either is valid. See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut).

Comment: @JiahuiZhou, indeed it is.  In any case, I believe your issue  may have to do with ordering. Try updating your code with my answer below and let me know if it solves your problem (or at least give you a more useful console.log)

Comment: @Jiahui Zhou, did that work for you?